# unable to initialize a array on heap of size 1000000000

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I am new to dynamic programming ,I was learning about recursion by solving  this question

My Doubt

1) Since test case is very large How to decide the size of `dp` table , according to my knowledge we decide the size of table by the value of n;
Please let me know what should correct table size ,because we don,t know how many sub problems going to repeat , i am little confused ;

2) As we know vector dynamically allocates memory on heap and declaring globally a vector mean only pointer variable `dp` will occupy space in global section ,`1000000000* sizeof(int)` will be occupied in heap.Then why it showing error `std::bad alloc` Because we can allocate memory as much as we want on heap

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    vector <int> dp(1000000001,-1);
    int exchange(int n){
        if(n<12)
            return n;
        if(dp[n]!=-1)
            return dp[n];
        return dp[n] = exchange(n/2)+exchange(n/3)+exchange(n/4);
    }
    int main(){
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--){
      //      memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
            int n;
            cin>>n;
            cout<<exchange(n);
        }

    }
```

EDIT

Note-> count()  The function returns the number of times the key K is present in the map container. It returns 1 if the key is present in the container as the map only contains a unique key. It returns 0 if the key is not present in the map container.
It is passing nearly all the test cases but it is failing `1 000 000 000`
according to long long int range value it should pass this one also but it giving 
some negative value as output ; 
I think this is the problem with container map

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    map <long long int,long long int> dp;
    int exchange(long long int n){
        if(n<12)
            return n;
        if(dp.count(n))
            return dp[n];
        return dp[n] = exchange(n/2)+exchange(n/3)+exchange(n/4);
    }
    int main(){
     //   int t;
       // cin>>t;
        while(1){
      //      memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
            long long int n;
            cin>>n;
            cout<<exchange(n)<<endl;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? 'Because we can allocate memory as much as we want on heap' is somehow limited ;)

Comment: It seems to me that vector allocates ONE block of memory, so it is possible that it doesn't found 100MB free block(memory fragmentation). It may be possible to allocate 2x50MB. As I read there is possibility of using plenty of GBs(2-4) per one process, of course if your machine has so much memory.

Comment: @BartekPL Well, it is `1'000'000'001 * sizeof(int)` bytes of memory, i. e. around 4 GB of memory...

Comment: @Aconcagua Oh yes... I missed some zeros xD

Comment: oh my good that is too large

Comment: should i go for a cloud service to  run this program laugh:

Comment: You don't. See my answer.

Comment: @coder1212 Not relevant any more since it seems a vector is not the way to go, but to answer question 1, resize the vector *after* you know how big it needs to be `vector <int> dp; ... dp.resize(n,-1);`.

Comment: Don't include `bits/stdc++.h`, it is non-standard, wont work with most compilers and may not even work with future versions of c++. There is no need to preallocate `dp` before you know the value of `t`, just create/resize the vector to `t` after it is input. Are you compiling to 64-bit? You are allocating 4GB of memory which will fail on a 32-bit process.

Comment: Are you building 32 or 64 bit? Not being able to allocate 4e9 contiguous bytes (assuming 32 bit `int`) in 64 bit surprises me, on 32 bit it will necessarily fail; contiguous or otherwise. Note also that the memory is contiguous in the probably at least twice abstracted sense - it doesn't mean the physical memory is contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the immediate problem by doing:

```
vector <int> dp;

// ....

cin>>t;
dp = std::vector<int>(t, -1);
```

This will dynamically allocate the memory based on the entered `t`, and you can use exceptions to catch if the user enters too large a value.

Comment: can you predict the size of dp table

Comment: The allocation will be roughly `t * sizeof(int)`, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

While your input size may be very large, note that the vast majority of your table will not be inspected. For an input of 999,999,999 you will only ever touch 230 values of `exchange(n)`. Roughly speaking, you will descend `log_2(n)` times with a branching factor of 2 (since the n/4 case is covered by n/2 applied twice).

For this concrete example, you're thus better off using a `map<int, int>` or an `unordered_map<int, int>`.

Your concrete `exchange` function might look like the following:

```
std::map<int, int> dp;

int exchange(int n) {
    if (n < 12) return n;
    auto it = dp.find(n);
    if (it != dp.cend()) return it->second;

    int val = exchange(n/2) + exchange(n/3) + exchange(n/4);
    dp.insert({n, val});
    return val;
}
```

Comment: what does  `dp.cend()` here can we use `dp.end()` here?

Comment: I search in stack overflow about dp.cend() but didn't get can you explain that in simple words?

Comment: @coder1212 `cend()` is [constant end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end)

Comment: Wont this just double (or more) the amount of memory used?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Assuming that the array was densely filled, yes. However, for a very sparsely filled data structure it makes sense. See my remark about only needing 230 elements.

Comment: `exchange(1'000'000'000) = 4243218150` which does not fit in a signed 32-bit int. Switch to `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long int`.

Answer (score 0):

Vector allocates ONE block of memory, so it is possible that it doesn't found free memory block(read about memory fragmentation).

What's [more](https://www.viva64.com/en/k/0036/), there is possibility of using max 2GB per one process on 32bit systems and 8TB on 64bit systems, of course if your machine has so much memory.

Comment: `std::vector` guarantees contiguous memory - and you need to keep this guarantee even with custom allocator. `std::deque` would be an alternative container allowing fragmented memory internally.

Comment: @Aconcagua There are much smarter people than me on SO. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Possibly rather a matter of *experience* ;) - I've been in this business for quite a while now...